# how to pass parameter in include() , ejs?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs, web-deployment

I am including header and footer file in home.ejs file in my project but I want to pass a string that will be a CSS stylesheet file name , like I am including that header file in my home.ejs file so when I include I want to pass a string to `include()` and add it to `href` of my link tag in header.ejs file in that way I can add diff stylesheet for diff ejs files

the link tag above which I have commented // custom stylesheet that's the link tag

code for header.ejs file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- fonts -->
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Reggae+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- boostrap CDN -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- custom CSS stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css"   >
<title>Yuvraj</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg ">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Yuvraj Agarkar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <img class="navbar-toggler-icon" src="../images/More.svg" alt="not found" style="height: 50px; width: 50px;">
      <!-- <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> -->

    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="/about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="/newsletter">Newsletter</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Posts</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle active" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown link
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">fundamentals</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">top iOS tips</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">General programmic habbits</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

code for home.ejs file , here I want to pass that string name

```html
<%-  include('partials/header') -%>
<div class="introDiv">
    
        <div class="intro">
            <h2 class="introLine">I am a aspiring <span class="profSpan"> </span> <span class="cur">|</span></h2>
            
        </div>
        
        <div class="imageDiv">
            <img class="svgImages" src="/images/catSleeping.svg" alt="Not found">
            <h4 class="hustle">**Keep Hustling**</h4>
        </div>
    
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row color">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6 article">
            <img src="/images/laptop-code.jpg" alt="article-image" class="article-img">
            <h3>
                Foundation of programming
            </h3>
            <h5>
                lorem ipsm is the dummy rext rerbsite the dummy rext rerbsite the dummy rext rerbsite 
            </h5>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6 article">
            <img src="/images/man-code.jpg" alt="article-image" class="article-img">
            <h3>
                Basics of programming
            </h3>
            <h5>
                lorem ipsm is the dummy rext rerbsite the dummy rext rerbsite the dummy rext rerbsite 
            </h5>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div>
<%-  include('partials/footer') -%>
```

Comment: modern HTML note: don't use `href="#"` in an anchor. If you're adding an href later, add it later, but for a decade now the meaning of `href="#"` is "scroll to the top of this document". Unless that's what you actually mean (and in this case it definitely isn't) don't put it in your markup. As for your EJS question: what's _processing_ the ejs? Because the normal approach is to pass in your variables as EJS render context, and EJS will automatically pick that varname up, all well-documented over on https://ejs.co/#install

Comment: @AliEsmailpor , i want to pass an argument to include() that argument will be name of a css file and i want to add that variable content in href address for example 
``` include('header',{name:name})  ``` 
IN HEADER FILE
``` <link href="/css/{that name here}">  ```